# Repacking Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I've heard that you can customize and repack your distro, I'd like to know if i can repack Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Running on my PC.
(I have all the current updates installed, and would like to make an image of my OS)

1. Is it Possible?
2. If yes, How?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall, though most information on this is old.

Comment: Thanks @muru. I did some research and found  'Remastersys'. I think it should do the trick. Cheers!